# Building Flutter Engine on Ubuntu

Tags: flutter, dart, chromium

I use Ubuntu 20.04. When I run https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Setting-up-the-Engine-development-environment step 7

```
 sudo ./build/install-build-deps-android.sh
ERROR: Only Ubuntu 12.04 (precise), 14.04 (trusty),  14.10 (utopic), 15.04 (vivid), 16.04 (xenial), 18.04 (bionic),  and Debian (rodete and stretch) are currently supported
```

And the doc says:

```
If you're on Linux, run the following. Note: These scripts are distro- and version-specific, so are not guaranteed to work on every configuration. If they fail, you may need to find comparable packages to the ones that weren't found.
```

Based on the documentation, How do I know which packages are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify that install-build-deps-android.sh script and force 20.04 and try to go on the building process?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).